# Существуют ли готовые решения Swipe-меню для RecyclerView?

Tags: android, swipe

Существуют ли готовые решения swipe-меню для `RecyclerView`? 
Находил библиотеки только для `ListView`, может кто подскажет версии для `RecyclerView`?

Нужно получить такой результат:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Описывайте свою проблему максимально точно прямо в вопросе, картинки только для дополнительного пояснения потому, что их могут и не увидеть ( как в вашем случае), кроме того у этого ресурса есть собственный хостинг картинок, пользуйтесь им.

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы при свайпе появлялось меню с действиями, как например [это](https://github.com/rahulrj/Swipe_RecyclerView)? Вообще вопросы по поиску внешних библиотек на этом ресурсе не жалуют, поэтому в дальнейшем сначала попробуйте [сделать как то так](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=swipe+recyclerview).

Comment: pavlofff, Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существуют, и их достаточно много.
В последний раз использовал [AndroidSwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout)